# How to link this javascript and php?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I was wondering if someone could point me in the right direction on how to do this.

As you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/caute6y0/ I have a grid where you can select squares and they will be highlighted. Now, I want the user to be able to submit their selection and it gets sent to my database.

So could someone give some pointers on how I can know know which boxes have been selected, and then how to have that information sent to the database via php?

Thanks

```
<body>
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="800" height="800" style="position: absolute;
top:0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin:auto;border: 1px solid grey;"></canvas>
```

```
window.onload = window.onresize = function() {
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 0.8;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 0.8;
}


function getSquare(canvas, evt) {
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
return {
    x: 1 + (evt.clientX - rect.left) - (evt.clientX - rect.left)%10,
    y: 1 + (evt.clientY - rect.top) - (evt.clientY - rect.top)%10
};
}

function drawGrid(context) {
for (var x = 0.5; x < 10001; x += 10) {
  context.moveTo(x, 0);
  context.lineTo(x, 10000);
}

for (var y = 0.5; y < 10001; y += 10) {
  context.moveTo(0, y);
  context.lineTo(10000, y);
}

context.strokeStyle = "#ddd";
context.stroke();
}

function fillSquare(context, x, y){
context.fillStyle = "black"
context.fillRect(x,y,9,9);
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');

drawGrid(context);

canvas.addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
var mousePos = getSquare(canvas, evt);
fillSquare(context, mousePos.x, mousePos.y)
}, false);
```

Comment: First off, you need some way of triggering the submission to the server-side language. Either a button on your canvas or a test for a limit on the number of squares selected. Next you will need to determine on the method of submitting the data - a regular form + data or Ajax. Then you will need to extract the co-ordinates of the boxes selected then submit them to your server-side language.

Comment: Hey, yeah the only part i'm struggling with is extracting the coordinates of the boxes selected and putting that into a form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an array of all the points that the user has selected.  As I have done in this example:
https://jsfiddle.net/caute6y0/2/

Then post that data to the server in json format use the following jquery:

```
var myDataObj = new Object();
myDataObj.points = points;

$.ajax({  
  type: "POST",
  url: "www.example.com/test.php",
  data: JSON.stringify(myDataObj),
  contentType: "application/json"
});
```

Then on the php side you just need to parse the POST data and save it to the database

```
<?php
$myPoints = json_decode($_POST['points']);
//Save to Database

$sql = "Insert into MYTABLE (Point,UserName) VALUES (?,?)";
$db =new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=database;","root","");
$sth = $db->prepare($sql);
foreach($myPoints as $point)
{
    $sth->execute(array($point,$username));
}
```